# Web Service Class Cast Exception

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I am currently using JBoss 5.1.0 and have an ejb deployed that makes use of an WebService on a remote system.  I recently received a new VM that had an updated JBoss configuration and now after deploying and when trying to call a method on the webservice, I get the following error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:  org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPElementImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader

I have generated the java web service bindings from the WSDL and it has been working.  There must be some classpath issue going on here but I am not sure where to begin to look.

-Rob

Looks like the picketlink libraries were added to the JBoss instance for webservice security some some webservices that are deployed on that local instance.  The remote web service I am calling does not make use of this.

Comment: You need to find out what changed between those JBoss configs. Was it the same version of JBoss?  Can do a diff between the filesets to see what changed?

Comment: Looks like the picketlink libraries were added to the JBoss instance for webservice security some some webservices that are deployed on that local instance.  The remote web service I am calling does not make use of this.

Answer (score 5):

This issue in `jbossws-native-3.2.0` was fixed in `jbossws-native-3.2.2`. Please try upgrading.

Here is the relevant issue from the JBoss Web Services issue tracker:

[JBWS-2746: ClassCastException because SOAPEnvelopeImpl blindly casts to SOAPElementImpl](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-2746)